# Why is my Python script causing 100% processor usage? While loop to monitor GPIO button

Tags: python

```
import json
from gpiozero import Button
from time import sleep
from mpd import MPDClient

button = Button(23)
while True:
    if button.is_pressed:
        client = MPDClient()               # create client object
        client.timeout = 10                # network timeout in seconds (floats allowed), default: None
        client.idletimeout = None          # timeout for fetching the result of the idle command is handled seperately, default: None
        client.connect("localhost", 6600)  # connect to localhost:6600
        client.load("Radio")
        if (client.status()['state']=="play"):
            client.pause()
        else:
            client.play()
        sleep(1.25)
        print ("State is:")
        print (client.status()['state'])
        client.close()                     # send the close command
        client.disconnect()                # disconnect from the server
```

I call this script in my bashrc file:

```
python ~/scripts/gpio/gpiompdstartstop.py &
```

I tried increasing the sleep time within the cycle, but it doesn't help at all...

I am considering investigating how to use a subprocess call, but I'm not sure it would help, nor how to go about it.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: NOTE even with the "fix" this is poor practice. Use a callback or wait for press.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I have zero knowledge about that. If you can share an example I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sleep is only executed if the button is pressed.  You need a sleep between checks for the button press to let other processes run.

E.g.

```py
while True:
    if button.is_pressed:
        # do work
    time.sleep(0.05) # check for button press 20 times a second.
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I'm an idiot. Added sleep for a second and fixed my issue. At least my first impression was correct, even though I failed to solve the problem. Any idea why there are two processes listed?

Comment: Do you mean Linux processes?  There will be the bash shell process and the Python process for your script.  The bash shell script will exist until your Python script ends.

Comment: Htop shows 2 lines with the same content (the script command): python ~/scripts/gpio/gpiompdstartstop.py &
The way I had it before showed a few more repeated ones...

Answer (score 0):

GpioZero is far easier for beginners to use (and unlike RPi.GPIO it ACTUALLY has **DOCUMENTATION** and **EXAMPLES**)

See the [Button class](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_input.html#button)

I would probably use `when_pressed`.
As your code is doing little you could use `wait_for_press` which will block until needed.

Incidentally calling from `.bashrc` is an extremely POOR practice. This is designed for configuring the shell **NOT** running programs.